# proxy authentication using jetty

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, jetty, proxy-server

I am trying to find out if it is possible to do proxy authentication in Java using jetty. I have been able to do basic and digest authentication schemes using jetty and there are easy ways in Jetty to set up these authentication schemes using pseudo code as this:

```
constraint = org.mortbay.jetty.security.Constraint();
constraint.setName(constraint.('__BASIC_AUTH'))
constraint.setRoles({'admin'});
constraint.setAuthenticate(true);
constraintMapping = ConstraintMapping();
constraintMapping.setConstraint(constraint);
constraintMapping.setPathSpec('/*');
securityHandler = SecurityHandler();
securityHandler.setUserRealm(myrealm);
securityHandler.setConstraintMappings(constraintMapping );
```

Similarly for DIGEST authentication __BASIC_AUTH can be replaced with __DIGEST_AUTH. I am using HttpServlets to handle requests/responses. However if I want to achieve proxy based authentication, how do I do this?

Do I need to use the httpservlet's doGet() and attempt authentication and explicit forwarding to another address or is there a way using jetty itself to setup a proxy based authentication(or a proxy localhost server) as shown in the pseudo above?

Can I get some help for code to do proxy based authentication that authenticates and forwards HttpServlet requests to another servlet/server?

Comment: The use of `org.mortbay.jetty` means you are using an *ancient* version of Jetty, long since EOL (End of Life).  The Jetty project moved to Eclipse foundation back in 2009, and changed its packaging to `org.eclipse.jetty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the [current version of Jetty (9.3.3.v20150827)](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/), the `Proxy-Authenticate` header is *not* related in any way to the `WWW-Authenticate` header that the Servlet constraint system.

There is nothing built into the the Servlet spec, or the Jetty implementation to support the `Proxy-Authenticate` client header from a Constraint point of view.

However, using Jetty 9.3.x you can use the the [`AsyncProxyServlet`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AsyncProxyServlet.html),  [`AsyncProxyServlet.Transparent`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AsyncProxyServlet.Transparent.html), [`AsyncMiddleManServlet`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AsyncMiddleManServlet.html), or [`AsyncMiddleManServlet.Transparent`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AsyncMiddleManServlet.Transparent.html) to have a means to handle this `Proxy-Authenticate` header in your own terms.

To accomplish this, you'll start by extending from one of those, and then overriding the [`sendProxyRequest(HttpServletRequest clientRequest, HttpServletResponse proxyResponse, Request proxyRequest)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/AbstractProxyServlet.html#sendProxyRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-org.eclipse.jetty.client.api.Request-).

In your version of `sendProxyRequest()`, look at the `clientRequest` headers for `Proxy-Authenticate` and `Proxy-Authorize`, and perform the Proxy based authentication that best suits your needs.

If the authentication passes, then call `super.sendProxyRequest(clientRequest, proxyResponse, proxyRequest);`.

Otherwise use the `proxyResponse` to send back the challenge response.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this!. So it seems that I will need to implement the sendProxyRequest method. However unlike doGet() that gets called automatically on sending a HTTP request, how does this method get invoked from the client and where is the url for this proxy server specified? Also, do you know if the proxy authentication can choose basic or digest as a scheme easily in this way?

Comment: I went ahead and filed an enhancement request for a better method that can be overridden for this behavior - https://bugs.eclipse.org/477201