# How to redirect request to an URI passed in headers with Jetty AsyncProxyServlet

Tags: spring-boot, proxy, kotlin, jetty

I'm creating a proxy micro-service with SpringBoot, Jetty and kotlin.

The purpose of this micro-service is to forward requests made by my front-end application to external services (avoiding CORS) and send back the response after checking some custom authentication. The query I'll receive will contain the URL of the target in the headers (i.e: `Target-Url: http://domain.api/getmodel`).

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32514353/1436679), I made a class that extends `AsyncProxyServlet` and overwrote the method `sendProxyRequest` :

```
class ProxyServlet : AsyncProxyServlet() {

    private companion object {
        const val TARGET_URL = "Target-Url"
    }

    override fun sendProxyRequest(clientRequest: HttpServletRequest, proxyResponse: HttpServletResponse, proxyRequest: Request) {
        // authentication logic

        val targetUrl = clientRequest.getHeader(TARGET_URL)

        if (authSuccess) {
            super.sendProxyRequest(clientRequest, proxyResponse, proxyRequest)
        } else {
            proxyResponse.status = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value()
        }
    }

}
```

When I query my proxy, I get in this method and successfuly authenticate, but I fail to understand how to use my targetUrl to redirect the request.

The method keeps calling itself as it's redirecting the original request to itself (the request from http://myproxy:port/ to http://myproxy:port/).

It is very difficult to find documentation on this specific implementation of jetty, StackOverflow is my last resort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, setup logging for Jetty, and configure DEBUG level logging for the package namespace `org.eclipse.jetty.proxy`, this will help you understand the behavior much better.

The `Request proxyRequest` parameter represents a `HttpClient/Request` object, which is created with an immutable URI/URL destination (this is due to various other features that requires information from the URI/URL such as Connection pooling, Cookies, Authentication, etc), you cannot change the URI/URL on this object after the fact, you must create the `HttpClient/Request` object with the correct URI/URL.

Since all you want to do is change the target URL, you should instead be overriding the method ...

```java
protected String rewriteTarget(HttpServletRequest clientRequest)
```

... and returning the new absolute URI String to the destination that you want to use (The `"Target-Url"` header in your scenario looks like a good candidate)

You can see this logic in the [`ProxyServlet.service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.12.v20180830/jetty-proxy/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/proxy/ProxyServlet.java#L59-L120) code block (which `AsyncProxyServlet` extends from)

Comment: Thank you! I did not see your answer and ended up implementing this exact solution this morning. At least I learned for myself and I hope this will help others one day.